# Copying only nested folders

Tags: r, file-copying

I think this is a problem with a simple fix but I keep hitting dead ends. I have a folder, let's call it "A", containing many subfolders. Each subfolder contains files. I want to copy the subfolders within A to a different folder, not the folder A itself. I have tried the below, but it just ends up pasting folder A into my new_folder_path. What am I missing here?

```
file.copy(folder_A_path,new_folder_path, recursive = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the names of the files/dirs to copy:

```
file.copy(
  from = list.files(path = folder_A_path, full.names = T), 
  to = new_folder_path,
  recursive = TRUE
)
```